# CSS scroll problem

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100%;overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <asp:label id="lblInfo" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

My problem is vertical scroll always shown. My destination is when div inner text empty or not overflowed from height, scroll will hidden.

How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100%;overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;">
    <asp:label id="lblInfo" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

will do it.

See

[overflow-y](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530829%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Content is clipped and scrolling is
>   added only when necessary.